# Using of vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having trouble with the following code and can't seem to figure out what is wrong

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double distance(int a, int b)
{
    return fabs(a-b);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> age;
    age.push_back(10);
    age.push_back(15);

    cout<<distance(age[0],age[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The error lies at calling of function distance.

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h: In instantiation of ‘std::iterator_traits<int>’:
test.cpp:18:30:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:166:53: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:167:53: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:168:53: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:169:53: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:170:53: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type
```

Comment: I want to store data in a vector array (for dynamic size), then calculate the distance between the data points.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are trying to override std::distance function, try removing "`using namespace std`" and qualifying `cout` and `endl` with `std::`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>


double distance(int a, int b)
{
    return fabs(a-b);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> age;
    age.push_back(10);
    age.push_back(15);

    std::cout<< distance(age[0],age[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The `std::distance` is used to count the number of elements in a container within a specified range. You can find more about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

Or you can rename your distance function if you want to introduce the `std::` namespace:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double mydistance(int a, int b)
{
    return fabs(a-b);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> age;
    age.push_back(10);
    age.push_back(15);

    cout<<mydistance(age[0],age[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

This will make your code work, but it is not recommended to have "using namespace" declarations before definitions. When you write your code, you should avoid the second option, it's shown here only as an alternative for your code example.

Comment: Or simply rename your own distance function and remove the clash with `std::distance`.

Comment: @Mithrandir That is a quick and cheap fix. I prefer the posters answer.

Comment: @Mithrandir, no, "simply" is "don't bring another namespace into global namespace", because *that's why we have them*!

Comment: @Mithrandir: namespaces are there to _enable_ you to reuse names. If you fear name-clashes and code around them, you are using namespaces wrong or did not understand them.

Answer (score 9):

How about

```
cout<< ::distance(age[0],age[1]);
```

(other answers already suggest removing the `using` directive).

Comment: This is a worthwhile thing to know about the scope resolution operator, but I wouldn't put it in production code unless avoiding it would cause big, big problems. None the less +1 for useful trivia.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `using namespace std` when you're creating your own function called `distance`, because your call to `distance` is looking for `std::distance` and not your `distance` function.

You could also do this:

```
namespace foo
{
  double distance(int a, int b)
  {
    return fabs(a-b);
  }
}

int main()
{
   foo::distance(x,y); //now you're calling your own distance function.
}
```

Comment: Looks like he has his own `distance` implementation

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use

```
 using foo::distance; // OR:
 using namespace foo;

 (distance)(x,y); // the (parens) prevent ADL
```